# How to send request parameters to spring webflow controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

i am new to webflow ,i tried with below code ,whats the wrong in this...

```
<view-state id="displayAllTasks" view="/WEB-INF/flows/jsp/displayAllTasks.jsp" model="workflowSet">
 <on-render>
   <set name="requestScope.state" value="requestParameters.state"/>       
   <evaluate expression="workflowController.getAllTasksByState(requestParameters.state)" result="viewScope.workflowSet"></evaluate>
 </on-render>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace on-render tag with on-entry , it will work.

```
<view-state id="displayAllTasks" view="/WEB-INF/flows/jsp/displayAllTasks.jsp" model="workflowSet">
<on-entry>
<set name="requestScope.state" value="requestParameters.state"/>       
<evaluate expression="workflowController.getAllTasksByState(requestParameters.state)"   result="viewScope.workflowSet"></evaluate>
</on-entry>
```